# PHPExcel Error - Running example

Tags: php, excel

I've just downloaded and installed the PHPExcel framework on my local server as per the installation process here. https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/install.txt

But running the sample test `http://localhost/Tests/02types.php` keeps giving me this error:

```
08:10:37 Create new PHPExcel object
08:10:37 Set document properties
08:10:37 Set default font
08:10:37 Add some data
08:10:37 Rename worksheet
08:10:37 Write to Excel2007 format
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /var/www/Tests/02types.xlsx.' in /var/www/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:378 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/Tests/02types.php(124): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('/var/www/Tests/...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 378
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? 
Any help would be apprciated.

Helen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the zip file can't be closed, then it means one of two things:

either

> You have any existing zip file open in another application

or

> Your PHP doesn't have the relevant permissions to write to the directory where it's trying to create the zip file

Comment: Thanks for your replay - will look into it and let you know if I manage to get it working. But, I'm sure I didn't have any existing zip file open.

Comment: It didn't have permission to write to the current directory. Changing the permission helped. Thanks again